# Detecting the Concepts TS with GCC 6.1

Tags: c++, g++, c++-concepts

How can I detect the presence of the Concepts TS with GCC 6.1?

[This page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/feature_test) suggests that the macro `__cpp_experimental_concepts` should be predefined in a Concepts TS-supporting implementation. However, the following test program compiles without error on GCC 6.1 with the `-fconcepts` flag:

```
#ifdef __cpp_experimental_concepts
static_assert(false, "Concepts TS found");
#endif

template <typename T>
concept bool Identity = true;

int main() {}
```

(I would expect either the `static_assert` to fire, or the `concept` keyword to go unrecognised.)

Does anyone know of any other method to conditionally compile code based on whether Concepts are available?

Comment: You can find the macro with `echo | g++ -E -dM -fconcepts -x c++ - | fgrep concepts`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct macro is `__cpp_concepts` for GCC:

```
#ifdef __cpp_concepts
static_assert(false, "Concepts TS found");
#endif
```

According to [this](https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/505062/), the name of the macro was changed in a recent draft.

The correct name is from the [GCC support page](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#tses) (thanks to [Jonathan Wakely](https://stackoverflow.com/users/981959/jonathan-wakely)), but the [linked draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4377.pdf) (2015-02-09) still requires `__cpp_experimental_concepts` (which is strange... ). However, in this [more recent draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0121r0.pdf) (2015-09-25), the name has actually been changed to `__cpp_concepts`.

Comment: Strange that it's no longer considered experimental considering it's still a TS, but this is exactly what I needed -- thanks very much for the quick response.

Comment: The macro and its official value are documented at https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#tses (g++ seems to set it to 201500 not 201507 for now)

Comment: @JonathanWakely Looks like there is an inconsistency here since this value is from an old draft where `__cpp_experimental_concepts` was still use.